# C# AWS S3 SDK copy object to a different region

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have googled this extensively and have found a few references to coping files to a folder in a different region, but none of the examples show where/how to declare the second region and most don’t identify either region.  The best I found so far is this method:

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, region);
client.CopyObject(sourceBucket, awsSourceKey, destBucket, awsDestKey);
```

I’m going to assume the region specified here is the source region.  How to I specify the destination region?

If I F12 on the method "CopyObject" I get to the source and read the source comments where it states:

"Both the Region that you want to copy the object from and the Region that you want to copy the object to must be enabled for your account."

So it's clear we can have a source and destination region, but there's no mention or example of how to specify both regions.

Can someone kindly shed some light on this please?

Thank  you.

Comment: You don't need to specify either region.  The source region will be discovered with a 307 redirect, and the underlying S3 REST API only needs the bucket name, the region of the target bucket is discovered by S3 behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Thank you @AnonCoward.  This helps a LOT!  How does S3 discover the target region?  Are keys (paths) unique across regions also?  Also, the target bucket may require different credentials (key and secret) and none of the code examples I see provide a way to enter 2 sets of key-secrets.

Comment: Bucket names are in a global namespace, they're all unique across accounts and regions.  The S3 Copy API, like all AWS APIs, operates with the permissions of one set of credentials, if you're copying from one account to another, you will need [cross-account permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/).